# How can I prevent "OC GURU II" from running at bootup?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I recently installed the [Gigabyte VGA - OC GURU II](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/utility.aspx?cg=3) application to underclock my graphics memory.

However I find that when I login to Windows 10 Home, it seems to run a CMD window and fire up the application. I've tried as many places as I can think of to find out what's causing this, but I'm out of ideas.

Places I've looked,

- The `Startup` tab of Task Manager
- In `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
- The various `Run` and `RunOnce` [registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Task Scheduler application

I cannot find the executable in any of these places, and was wondering if anyone has any suggestions how I might track down what is causing this application to run on startup.

Thanks!

Comment: use autoruns from sysinternals https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Great! Thanks, if you could convert your comment to an answer, I can accept it. Turns out it was in Task Scheduler!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage startup entries, you should always use [Autoruns from Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of
>   auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what
>   programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and when
>   you start various built-in Windows applications like Internet
>   Explorer, Explorer and media players. These programs and drivers
>   include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry
>   keys. Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser
>   helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much
>   more. Autoruns goes way beyond other autostart utilities.

Look here for the entry of `OC GURU II` and uncheck the tool to prevent startup at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the exe *should* be easy enough using task manager, once the program has started look under the "Processes" Tab of Task Manager for a program that fits the name. From there you can right click on it and go to "Open File Location", which will open explorer at the folder where the exe is located and also highlight the exe itself. The same process can be accomplished from the "Details" tab of Task Manager if you cannot find the program in the "Processes" tab.

You might be able to spot the .cmd or .bat file that runs at startup in this folder, if not try putting ".cmd" or ".bat" in the folder's search bar as this will search any subfolders for you, and try the same after stepping up one folder.

If after this you can't find that startup file try renaming the exe you found by deleting/adding in a letter before the ".exe" ending and reboot. If the .bat/.cmd file was well written, it should encounter an error and stay open when it cant find the .exe after you changed the name. You can then use Task Manager to open the file location of the CMD window process which should highlight the file you're looking for.

Hope this helps!